# Subordinating conjunction or preposition

Tags: grammar

Why is the existence of subordinating conjunctions not accepted by many on this forum. Instead they call these words as preposition .examples-Than, before, after, while,  because etc.

Comment: https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=9494 Geoffrey Pullum outlines the arguments pretty well. Scroll to the bottom and download the paper, section 6 deals with your question.

Comment: What we *call* things is often in dispute. For instance, I have a dislike of some of the linguistic terminology used here that doesn't match common terms used by dictionaries and standard grammar texts. I believe that if we are to limit our vocabulary to linguistic terms only, then this site should be no different than the already existing [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) site. But I deliberately keep to the more common terminology, because this is *not* a niche site and it shouldn't be using niche terminology. However, many things can be described differently.

Comment: Jason,  you are on which side -subordinator or preposition? Imagine the plight of non natives  trying to learn the language having so many differences among linguists

Comment: The words quoted - than, before, after, while, because etc. - become different functionaries based on the functions for sure. It is not that 'before' is only a conjunction, but is used as a preposition too, and even adverb.  The context contributes to it.  Would have been ideal, had you also posted the relevant sentence examples of the link you quoted above for the ease of audience.

Comment: Yes Mr Ram Pillai. It all started when I sought the sentence analysis of He is taller than Jack but shorter than John. I assumed it to be an example of compound-complex  sentence having two co-ordinate clauses joined by but and two subordinate clauses (having two than)  .if we expand it becomes he is taller than Jack is but he is shorter than John is. However on this forum i was told that it's a simple sentence with 'than' being a preposition and co-ordinator 'but'  adding a phrase to the main sentence.Thanks